# Regex - How to allow white space comma and letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate text field using JavaScript. It should allow (a-z, white space between words, and A-Z).

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
function formValidator(){
   var name = document.getElementById('name');

if(isAlphabet(name, "Please enter only letters for your  name")){
return true;
}
return false;
}
     function isAlphabet(elem, helperMsg){
        var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z.,\b]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: `alphaExp.test("foo bar"); // true` So what's the issue? What does *"doesn't work"* mean?

Comment: You need to provide some examples of valid and invalid strings. It sounds like you want a comma space `, ` delimited list?

Comment: Your regex also allows the character `?`; I bet that's unintentional.

Comment: From what I can infer, the only requirement you're not getting right is *white space between words*. The current regex allows string to start with white space, same with comma.

Comment: @user4210296 What if someone's name is `O'Malley` or `Álvarez`?

Comment: See http://regex101.com/r/zC2sU7/1

Comment: @user4210296 Please mark one of the answers as accepted if your question is satisfactorily answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your regex should look like this:

```
/^[a-z]+(\s+[a-z]+)*$/i
```

This allows A-Z (case-insensitive because of `/i`), followed by any amount of white-space characters and A-Z again. The last part may be repeated or doesn't need to be present at all.

Comment: Does this one also works for special characters?

Comment: No, `[a-z]` allows only the letters from A-Z, without accents, like à or ö. If you want to allow any so-called word character, you can replace `[a-z]` with `\w`: `/^\w+(\s+\w+)*/`

Answer (score 0):

Allow only single space between words:

```
/^[a-z]+( [a-z]+)*$/i.test(str);
```